# How to get the actual Datum that android GPS is using?

Tags: android, gps

I need to get the actual Datum that the Android GPS is using, but I can't find a method that returns it for me. I know that the it uses the WGS84 Datum as default, but doesn't it change according to the location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WGS84 is the geographic Datum of course!
WGS84 is both: an ellipsoid world wide valid, and a geographic datum too.

Theoretically the GPS chips itself can be configured to use another ellipsoid and Datum, but not in Android or iOS. If you need another datum, take the WGS84 latitude and longitude, and convert yourself. (But you nearly never need that)

This well defined WGS84 Datum is especially valid for latitude and longitude.

For the height (or called altitude) attribute, I don't know if it is above mean Sea Level (then it would be difficult to find out how this was calculated, usually by the GPS chip, too).
If the height is above (WGS84) ellipsoid then the height Datum (vertical Datum) is clearly defined.

Comment: Thanks, AlexWien! I just needed to know for sure if it was really the WGS84 or another one and if it changes according to the location!